# Does any one knows what this error means "The /usr/lib/apt/methods/hyyps method driver could not be found"

Tags: apt, 22.04

I'm still a newbie in the Linux world, although I've been using it for a few years. However, I'm having trouble understanding this error!:

```
E: The method driver /usr/lib/apt/methods/hyyps could not be found.
```

I don't know how a "hyyps" can exist! Should I remove? If yes, how do I do it?

Thanks to anyone who can help.

**This is what i get when I type:** `ls -l /usr/lib/apt/methods`:

[image]

I can't see any "hyyps"!

I think I solved it, this is what I did: I opened the "software and updates" I unchecked everything as in the image [image: image_1]and I did an apt update and I noticed that the error does not appear...[image: image_2]but the spelling errors have a solution?

Comment: Do you really get `/usr/lib/apt/methods/hyyps ....` ot `/usr/lib/apt/methods/https ...` ? And what is the output of `file /usr/lib/apt/methods/http` ?

Comment: Also please add the output of `ls -l /usr/lib/apt/methods/` to your question as well by [edit]ing it.

Comment: I have added an image, and yes I really get " /usr/lib/apt/methods/hyyps" i dis make an ls -l and i get that!

Comment: Yep! there is a `hyyps:/...` repository line in your picture ... click on it and then click on the **edit** button and change it to `https://...` ... It will work if it is actually a live(*not broken*) repository ... and please copy and paste text to your question(*don't add pictures*) whenever possible ,,, It's easier to read and search.

Comment: Also that **zesty** (*Ubuntu 17.04*) source should, probably, not be used at all on Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: Yes...i have remove it already...the error is not showing up no more after making update, something that hasn't happened before! Thanks .

Answer (score 11):

You, probably, have a misspelled/mistyped repository line that looks something like:

```
deb hyyps://...
```

instead of:

```
deb https://...
```

either in your main apt sources file:

```
/etc/apt/sources.list
```

or in the files under the directory:

```
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/
```

Find that line, correct it and this error should be resolved.

Comment: The fingers strike again. The keys are often side by side.